# Filtering stores location with login rules using GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, rule, directory

I want to filter the location/directory proposed by the stores, with the login rules.

More clearly, If my user "John" can only access/admin the "JohnWorkspace", I want he saw only one directory "dirForJohn" with the datastores for his Shapefile. and nothing else (no parent dir or what else).

Can I do that with GeoServer ?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not supported (not a trivial change either, at least if one intends to do it in a general enough way that it could be contributed to the official GeoServer code).